# Is there a way to denote the parent frame in Tkinter? I can't refer to the frame by name due to bad function writing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a frame with a checkbox and a X button in it. When I hit the X button, I want to delete that frame. Is there a way to denote parent frames? I can't refer to it by its variable name because I made it using a function so all the relevant frames share the same name.

My code:

```
import tkinter

master = tkinter.Tk()
master.title("test1")
master.geometry("300x300")

checkboxArea = tkinter.Frame(master)

checkboxArea.pack(fill=tkinter.X)

inputStuff = tkinter.Frame(master)

def removeInputStuff():
    inputStuff.pack_forget()
    buttonAdd.pack()
    buttonDone.remove()

buttonDone = tkinter.Button(inputStuff, text = "Close Input", command=removeInputStuff)

def createInputStuff():
    paddingFrame = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff, height=5)
    paddingFrame.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
    buttonDone.pack()
    inputStuff.pack()
    buttonAdd.pack_forget()

buttonAdd = tkinter.Button(master, text="Add Item", command=createInputStuff)
buttonAdd.pack()


topInput = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff)
bottomInput = tkinter.Frame(inputStuff)

topInput.pack()
bottomInput.pack()

def drawCheckboxAndDeleteInputBoxAndPrompt():
    nextToCheckbox = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0,tkinter.END)
    checkboxRow = tkinter.Frame(checkboxArea)
    checkboxRow.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
    checkbox1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(checkboxRow, text = nextToCheckbox)
    checkbox1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    deleteItem = tkinter.Button(checkboxRow, text = "x", bg="red", fg="white", activebackground="white", activeforeground="red")
    deleteItem.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

prompt = tkinter.Label(topInput, text="What do you want your checkbox to be for?")
prompt.pack()
entry = tkinter.Entry(bottomInput, bd=3)
entry.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
buttonConfirm = tkinter.Button(bottomInput, text="Confirm", command=drawCheckboxAndDeleteInputBoxAndPrompt)
buttonConfirm.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)

master.mainloop()
```

I would assign a function to delete checkboxRow, but I think that would delete all of my rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `command=checkboxRow.destroy` when the `deleteItem` button is created and it works (it only delete the intended item, not all of them).

So `drawCheckboxAndDeleteInputBoxAndPrompt` becomes

```
def drawCheckboxAndDeleteInputBoxAndPrompt():
    nextToCheckbox = entry.get()
    entry.delete(0,tkinter.END)
    checkboxRow = tkinter.Frame(checkboxArea)
    checkboxRow.pack(fill=tkinter.X)
    checkbox1 = tkinter.Checkbutton(checkboxRow, text = nextToCheckbox)
    checkbox1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
    deleteItem = tkinter.Button(checkboxRow, text = "x", bg="red", fg="white", 
                                activebackground="white", activeforeground="red", 
                                command=checkboxRow.destroy)
    deleteItem.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)
```